# AIR default forums?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I've seen a lot of useful default features that smart phone's provide. But calling on a lot of them is done through ANEs (such as distriqt's Dialog ane).

Is there one out there for a sort of default form creator? Something that will display fields like this?
[image]

Comment: You can browse the ANE directory (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html), however, I think you're looking in the opposite direction. What you probably need is to Google > Flex iOS skin.

Comment: Probably you need custom components, custom skins. Maybe you can learn something here: check https://github.com/rui-cruz/Spark-Material and https://github.com/quick6black/flex-Android-Material-Skins